# How to prevent direct access to pages url in nextjs when used rewrites?

Tags: next.js, routes

My problem is : I have `pages/blog.js` file in my project. I did localized urls like down below in the `next.config.js` file.

```
i18n:{
        locales:["tr","en"],
        defaultLocale:"tr"
      },
      async rewrites(){
        return [
                 {
                   "source":"/tr/makaleler",
                   "destination":"/blog",
                   "locale":false
                  },
                  {
                   "source":"/en/articles",
                   "destination":"/blog",
                   "locale":false
                   }
                ]
      }
```

It works. But problems is ; I can still access with this `localhost:3000/blog`. I want to make it only accessible with `localhost:3000/makaleler` or `localhost:3000/en/articles`.

Is there any way to achieve this? I have read "nextjs" documentation bu couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [Next.js Middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware) in version 12.2 if you want to implement complex redirect logic based on language (or anything). You can find a quick tutorial by Vercel in Youtube here: https://youtu.be/j7rPSS9Ovsw?t=296

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what you want is not possible, The reason is if you restrict access to `localhost:3000/blog` by any means, then your `rewrites` will stop working as well.

What you probably need is `redirects` from `localhost:3000/blog` to the desired locale for your users. You can leverage `Accept-Language` header for example:

```
async redirects() {
  return [
    {
      source: '/blog',
      has: [
        {
          type: 'header',
          key: 'accept-language',
          // header starts with tr
          value: 'tr(.*)',
        },
      ],
      destination: '/tr/makaleler',
      permanent: false,
    },
    {
      source: '/blog',
      has: [
        {
          type: 'header',
          key: 'accept-language',
          // header does not start with tr
          value: '((?!tr$).*)',
        },
      ],
      destination: '/en/articles',
      permanent: false,
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Probably closest solution for my situation.